# How to boot in to recovery on Xperia XA Ultra F3213 (single Sim)?

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, sony-xperia

I have gone through the process of doing the OEM Unlock.  I have debugger on.  I have attempted to boot into recovery using the following command.

C:\adb>fastboot boot recovery.img
response:
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  858s]
FAILED remote: oem unlock is false
finished. total time: 0.874s

If I attempt to Oem Unlock again is says its not needed.

I'm trying to root so I can remove bloat and free up some internal memory.

Comment: I believe Sony phones don't have dedicated recovery partitions. Your error seems different though - upvoted for awareness.

Comment: @AndyYan good point – but `fastboot boot` doesn't need a partition, just an image to load (and boot, one-time). Doesn't matter how the image file is named – could be `xmastree.img` though no Android device has an XMas-Tree built-in #D Which probably is why the response is "downloading 'boot.img'" (aka "I download something I hope I can boot from").